# Should I remove labels for which no node is in the database?

Tags: neo4j

In a neo4j database If I list all the labels with the `CALL db.labels()` it returns 216 records. Mainly because there has been lots of evolutions in this db. But if I list all the nodes and count them by label, I only have 35 records.

1. Is there a performance impact related to the amount of labels even if some labels have no node?
2. If so how can we remove them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create a label with an empty node. A label is a name you use to group nodes into a set. For example below, a node and 2 labels are created.

```
CREATE (n:Book:Fiction {name: 'Harry Potter', fiction: True})

Result: Added 2 labels, created 1 node, set 2 properties, completed after 26 ms.
```

Comment: I agree I don't think you can, but I believe what happened is that some nodes may have existed with this label but have been removed since. Also we do automatically create indexes based on a datamodel. So maybe we can actually create these labels without a node by creating an index?... I'll check that.

Comment: Just checked, you can actually create a label without creating a node, by creating an index
CREATE INDEX partid FOR (n:part) ON (n._id)
then CALL db.labels() returns the "part" label